# SSIS flat file location. Local drive vs shared folder on same server

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file stored locally on the same server where SSIS is running.

When choosing the location of my flat file in the flat file connection manager, I could use the local drive (d:\testfiles\flatfile.txt) or I could use the UNC path (\myserver\flatfileshare\flatfile.txt.)

Both are pointing at the same file and the package is succesful either way.  Is there a performance reason for why I should choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

More than a performance reason, if you choose the UNC path, you have a more flexible solution. In that case, if you change the SSIS package, so it runs on another server, the path to the file will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Specify your files like this:

`\\server\sharename\path\file.txt`

This will work in both places.

Referred to as a UNC path.

When I had XP, I loved this utility for generating them - [clippath](http://download.cnet.com/ClipPath/3000-2094_4-10050927.html).  You could right-click a file and it would copy the path to your clipboard.  Magical.

Now I'm on Win7 x64 and it's not supported.  Windows7 has a copy file path, but it seems to use the drive letter, which is not what we want, is it?

Looking up a file is a trivial location, I wouldn't worry about the diff.

Comment: I know it will work, and I'm familiar with UNC paths.  What I'm asking is: Are there any perfomance implications that I need to consider when choosing which one to use?

Comment: I'm not aware of any performance difference.  The file is located and then processed in the same exact way.  There may be a fraction of a second difference when looking up a UNC opposed to a LNC, but what's that worth?  Your optimization will happen in the package and in your data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use some sort of package configuration to store the path for the file, it's a much more flexible solution.